# Do I get free DLCs for Battlefield 4 if I am a premium user?

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm planning to buy Battlefield 4 on PS3. I'm aware that I get early access to the DLCs, but do they come for free then?

Comment: I got Premium, but in the store it says I have to buy every DLC except for Final Stand, and I can't play on any of the maps except for the Final Stand ones.

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. If you have premium downloaded and accessible on your console/PC, you will get all the DLC's.

Answer (score 8):

Not "Free". You are paying for them by purchasing Premium.

You also get access to many more features on Battlelog with Premium

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you got the Premium Game, so, with that, you get the DLC's for free.